# External stored procedure on IBM i

Tags: stored-procedures, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am trying to create an external stored procedure on an IBM i (V5R4), but I'm getting an error when I try to run it.

All I want to do is call an RPG program, without passing any parameters or worrying about returning any data. Sorry, I'm not an RPG programmer or an expert on IBM i, so I could be missing something very simple.

The SQL to create the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SOMELIB.SOMEPROC ( ) 

    LANGUAGE RPGLE 

    NOT DETERMINISTIC 

    NO SQL
    EXTERNAL NAME 'OTHERLIB/SOMERG' 

    PARAMETER STYLE GENERAL;
```

The error I get when executing CALL SOMELIB.SOMEPROC() is:

SQL State: 38501
Vendor Code: -443
Message: [CEE9901] Application error.  RNX1216 unmonitored by BB1002RG at statement 2100000001, instruction X'0000'. Cause . . . . . :   The application ended abnormally because an exception occurred and was not handled.  The name of the program to which the unhandled exception is sent is SOMERG SOMERG . The program was stopped at the high-level language statement number(s)  at the time the message was sent.  If more than one statement number is shown, the program is an optimized ILE program.  Optimization does not allow a single statement number to be determined.  If *N is shown as a value, it means the real value was not available. Recovery  . . . :   See the low level messages previously listed to locate the cause of the exception.  Correct any errors, and then try the request again.

Comment: Check higher in the job log.  You should see the error message from the SOMERG program.  Please post that error code.

Comment: We're not able to see anything else on the job log. :(

Comment: I re-read your message.  Do you see message RNX1216?  That's a file error message, but it should lead you further back to another message.  It's like following a crazy breadcrumb trail.  It looks like RNX1216 came from program BB1002RG if that helps.  Make sure the job's LOG parameter is set to (4 00 *SECLVL).

Comment: OK -- tracked down the error:
Cause . . . . . :   RPG procedure BB1002RG in program OTHERLIB/BB1002RG received the message CPF4101 while performing an implicit OPEN operation on file XYZ. The actual file is XYZ

So the BB1002RG program (which I referenced as SOMERG in the first message) works fine when called from the command line ... but when calling it through a stored procedure it seems like it doesn't know what library to find file XYZ in. Do I need to pass a library list somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your procedure is calling the RPG program without the library list set.  You can do one of two things:

1) Change the F-spec in the RPG program to qualify the library using the EXTFILE keyword.

2) Call a CL program from the stored procedure that adds the appropriate library to the library list making sure to allow for the fact that the library may already be there from a prior call.  Then have the CL program call the RPG program.

Comment: Looks like we'll take route #2. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

(a little bit more rude solution) Identify the user that starts the Stored Procedure. Change the jobdescription of that user to have the correct library list.

But in my experience is the CL program the most pragmatic solution too.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the file is in the same library as the program, add `EXTFILE(variablename)` and `USROPN` to the F-spec. Take the library name from the PSDS and construct the `variablename` value before you `OPEN` the file.

If the file and program are in different libraries, you might create a data area in the program library to hold the name of the data library. Retrieve the data area (using the PSDS) instead of using the PSDS (for the file library). If program and file aren't kept together, it can be a good idea to keep the data library name in an external object that can be changed rather than recompiling.

(Actually, I've rarely used data areas in the past ten years or so. Instead I create a user index. Each entry in the *USRIDX replaces a data area. The entries are keyed by a value that used to be a data area name. One object replaces many others and one procedure can manage all entries. One object to own and authorize reduces some system overhead.)

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion to get rid of this trouble: make the user profile JOBD contains all libraries needed by the stored procedure.